# Is it possible to get a visual indication of the status of the alert slider on Oneplus 3?

Tags: oneplus-3

I have a OnePlus 3 and I wasn't able to get any visual indication of the state of the alert slider (all/priority/silent). I keep missing calls because I forget to take it out of silent mode. On OnePlus 2 there was an icon showing the state of the slider - how is it possible to get one for OnePlus 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a support representative on their official chat told me that it was apparently a software problem and recommended that I perform hard reset (on a device a week old), it turns out that if you go to Status Bar settings, you need to turn on the switch called Do Not Disturb and you're done.